# Android app installation error: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Directory not empty

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I frequently get the following error when starting an app:

```
[2012-06-24 11:08:53 - Myapp] Failed to install Myapp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Directory not empty
[2012-06-24 11:08:53 - Myapp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Directory not empty
[2012-06-24 11:08:53 - Myapp] Launch canceled!
```

The only remedy that I have found so far is to start the emulator with "Wipe out user data" which is no big deal except all the time consuming customization is lost.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Saw something similar the other day when trying the Intel emulator image, went in with adb and concluded it's /data partition was seriously broken.  Perhaps try a different emulator image?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Intel emulator. Yes, I see this error only with the Intel emulator. I could go with another emulator, but the Intel one is indeed significant faster.