# Android : SyncException: Directory not empty?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an emulator that it's `snapshot` is enabled.My App has no error,but **some times** when I want to test my App on that emulator,installation failed and I see these in `console`:

> android com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Directory not empty

I try clean/build project,re open emulator,restart eclipse and even restart my PC.But it seems they can not solve this problem.Do you know what causes this problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178662/android-app-installation-error-com-android-ddmlib-syncexception-directory-not

Comment: I got this type Error in one time i just delete this emulator and recreate another problem is solve.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh It is not a recommended way.I need other Apps,data,... that are in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restart emulator from `snapshot` then `uninstall` my App from it and try again and no problem occurs.I don't know caused this problem,but it seems to be solved in this manner.